# Using funcarg value in pytest_generate_tests function

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am new to py.test and I am using funargs to generate some test data before the tests get executed. I want to have pytest_generate hook use the funcargs value and pass it to the test function. For e.g. I have a function "do_something" which queries a database for a given set of arguments and sets user's enviroment accordingly. Considering that we have a multi site setup, I want to ensure that the database has the entries against which the test is performed, before the test gets executed.

```
def pytest_funcarg__data(request):
    # Ensure test data exist in the data base
    # Perform all the checks
    # Final values
    values = [['option1', 'option2', 'option3'],
              ['option1', 'option2'],
              ['option2', 'option3']]
    # Expected result 
    results = [['output1'],
               ['output2'],
               ['output3']]

    return (values, results)

def test_do_something(value, result):       
    assert do_something(value) == result
```

Ideally. I want to iterate though the values and pass them to my test function. How can I do that?

Currently I am doing this:

```
def pytest_funcarg__data(request):
    #same as above

def pytest_funcarg__pass_data(request):
    data = request.getfuncargvalue("data")
    return (data[0][request.param],
                data[1][request.param])

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'pass_data' in metafunc.funcargnames:
        # If number of test cases change the change needs to made here too
        metafunc.parametrize("pass_data", [0, 1, 2], indirect=True)

def test_do_something(pass_data):
    assert do_something(pass_data[0] == pass_data[1]
```

Now, this works. But everytime I add a test case, I need to update the generate_test hook. I am thinking there might be a simpler way to do this ?

Comment: *How* does it not work? Please include a error description (and/or an exception, if there is any). Actually, I *think* I know what's the matter because I just spent two hours getting some complicated parametrization happen - but that's no excuse for you to be lazy!

Comment: Well the error is "metafunc does not have an attribute called getfuncargs". nor can the generate_test access the *data*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pytest_generate_tests hook is executed when tests are collected.  The pytest_funcarg__data factory is called when the test is executed.  Test execution happens after test collection so there is no way you could call something like "getfuncargvalue" during collection.

However, it's not clear from your example why you want to use both - here is a generate_tests that should work directly with your example test:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    params = [("input", "output")]
    metafunc.parametrize(("test_case", "result"), params)
```

HTH. holger

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated my original question for better clarity :)

Comment: I think there is a misconception at play here.  You do not need to pytest_funcarg__pass_data factory. It is enough to write a pytest_generate_tests function.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for clearing that out, I have removed the funcargs now and added the database calls to pytest_generate it pretty straightforward now :) thanks